# how to bind tabs in tabsheets in vaadin 8 with different URLs

Tags: hyperlink, routes, tabs, bookmarks, vaadin8

When I'm using Tabs in Flow, I'd like to link each Tab to a certain route, so that I can have each tab bound to a URL and the user can reach the wanted tab easily (e.g. bookmarks).

Tabsheet has Tab1 and Tab2 so i want have an URL that guides to Tab1 and another URL that guides to Tab2

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward way would be to use Navigator, and URI fragments. I assume that you would have TabSheet in a view, which has a name, and hence URL to that view. You can then use URI fragments to address tabs. This means that in "enter" method of the View you check the fragment and based on it select the Tab programmaticaly.